# jQuery remove element (LinkedIn)

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to remove the icon just leave text, jQuery tested on console mode, it works, but if I refresh the page, the icon still there. I tried CSS to hack it, but doesnt work either. If someone could help with this? Many thanks

HTML

```
<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="/in/jeffweiner08" data-format="hover"data-text="My profile" data-related="false"></script>
```

jQUery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.li-connect-mark').remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZH2PW/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS:

```
.li-connect-link:first-child {
    display: none;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('span a:first-child').hide();
```

or

```
 $('span a:first-child').remove();
```

Comment: Because, ur were testing with MooTools in Fiddle instead of JQuery. Working http://jsfiddle.net/ZH2PW/29/. Although the css solution is much better:P